# How do i display pagination data to table in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, pagination

I try to display specify paginate data to table...My paginate data contain json that already been decode in controller...I want display NICK_NAME in table

```
public function index()
{ 

 $response =  $this->client->get('getUserIndex')->getBody();
     $content = json_decode($response->getContents()); 
     $total = count($content) ;
     $collection = new \Illuminate\Support\Collection($content);
     $paginationRecord = CollectionPaginate::paginate($collection, $total, '15');
     return view('configuration.comuserprofiles.ComUserProfilesList', compact('paginationRecord'));
}
```

This is my dd of paginationrecord

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#4177 ▼
  #total: 1
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Collection {#4169 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      "data" => array:852 [▼
        0 => {#624 ▶}
        1 => {#623 ▶}
        2 => {#628 ▼
          +"ID": "cust1"
          +"PWD": "W6ph5Mm5Pz8GgiULbPgzG37mj9g="
          +"NICK_NAME": "CUST1"  //i want display this
          +"PWD_INVALID_HIT": "0"
          +"PWD_CREATE_DT": "2019/07/22 15:57:15"
          +"INSTITUTION_ID": "C01"
          +"ACL_ID": "L04"
          +"LOGIN_DT": "2019/07/22 15:57:15"
          +"LOGIN_STS_ID": "N"
          +"STS_ID": "C08"
          +"TYPE_ID": "U00"
          +"UPD_ID": "sufyzasukor"
          +"UPD_DT": "2019/07/22 15:57:15"
          +"EMAIL_ID": "cust1@gmail.com"
          +"PHONE_NO_ID": "0"
          +"HP_ID": "0                        "
          +"CRT_DATE_DELETED": null
          +"irel__com_access_level": {#621 …9}
          +"irel__com_user_types": {#630 …5}
          +"irel__com_status": {#631 …5}
        }
 ]
  }
  #perPage: "15"
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://localhost/IFICSV3/public/configuration/comuserprofiles"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
  +onEachSide: 3
  #options: array:2 [▶]
}
```

How do i write from here

```
<tbody>
          @foreach($paginationRecord as $i=>$user)
                   <td>$user ??<td>      
          @endforeach
</tbody>
```

How do i access and display data from LengthAwarePaginator ?? Sorry if my explaination no clear because this is something new for me

Answer (score 0):

When calling the paginate method, you will receive an instance of `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`

So, once you have retrieved the results, you may display the results and render the page links using Blade:

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        {{ $user->name }}
    @endforeach
</div>

{{ $users->links() }}
```

The links method will render the links to the rest of the pages in the result set. Each of these links will already contain the proper page query string variable.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination